# wpf -при создании копии шаблона удаляется "Path" из Binding

Tags: wpf

Есть стиль

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:Design_Style.Hellper"
                    xmlns:ConverterHellper="clr-namespace:Design_Style.Converter"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Design_Style">
    <ConverterHellper:RectConverter x:Key="RectConverter"></ConverterHellper:RectConverter>
    <ConverterHellper:DoubleToCornerRadius x:Key="DoubleToCornerRadius"></ConverterHellper:DoubleToCornerRadius>
    <Style x:Key="Style_ButtonRipple" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="local:ButtonRipple.CornerRadiusButton" Value="6"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#46BCFF"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Point x:Key="zero">0 0</Point>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" ClipToBounds="True" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding  local:ButtonRipple.CornerRadiusButton, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToCornerRadius}}"
                            helper:MouseHelper.IsDownPosition="True">
                        <Grid ClipToBounds="True" >
                            <!--Ripple Effect Body-->
                            <Path x:Name="ripplePath"
                               Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=(local:ButtonRipple.RippleColor)}">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <EllipseGeometry x:Name="rippleEllipse"
                                      Center="{Binding Path=(helper:MouseHelper.LastDownPosition), ElementName=templateRoot, TargetNullValue={StaticResource zero}}"
                                      RadiusY="{Binding RadiusX, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Border.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="helper:MouseHelper.LastMouseDown">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rippleEllipse"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RadiusX" BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.5" From="0" 
                                                         To="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                        
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ripplePath" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" BeginTime="0:0:0.0" Duration="0:0:0.6" From=".5" To="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Border.Triggers>
                        <Border.Clip>
                            <RectangleGeometry 
                              RadiusX="{TemplateBinding local:ButtonRipple.CornerRadiusButton}" 
                              RadiusY="{Binding RadiusX, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
                                <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RectConverter}">
                                        <Binding ElementName="templateRoot" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                        <Binding ElementName="templateRoot" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                            </RectangleGeometry>
                        </Border.Clip>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=(local:ButtonRipple.BackgroundMouseOver)}" TargetName="templateRoot"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

После создания копии шаблона
Код копии шаблона:

```
<Window.Resources>
     <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
         <Setter Property="local:ButtonRipple.CornerRadiusButton" Value="6"/>
         <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
         <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
         <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="#46BCFF"/>
         <Setter Property="Template">
             <Setter.Value>
                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                     <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                         <Point x:Key="zero">0 0</Point>
                     </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                     <Border x:Name="templateRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding local:ButtonRipple.CornerRadiusButton, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToCornerRadius}}" ClipToBounds="True" helper:MouseHelper.IsDownPosition="True">
                         <Border.Clip>
                             <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="{TemplateBinding local:ButtonRipple.CornerRadiusButton}" RadiusY="{Binding RadiusX, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
                                 <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RectConverter}">
                                         <Binding ElementName="templateRoot" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                                         <Binding ElementName="templateRoot" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                     </MultiBinding>
                                 </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                             </RectangleGeometry>
                         </Border.Clip>
                         <Border.Triggers>
                             <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="helper:MouseHelper.LastMouseDown">
                                 <BeginStoryboard>
                                     <Storyboard>
                                         <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.5" From="0" Storyboard.TargetName="rippleEllipse" To="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RadiusX"/>
                                         <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.0" Duration="0:0:0.6" From=".5" Storyboard.TargetName="ripplePath" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                     </Storyboard>
                                 </BeginStoryboard>
                             </EventTrigger>
                         </Border.Triggers>
                         <Grid ClipToBounds="True">
                             <Path x:Name="ripplePath" Fill="{Binding (local:ButtonRipple.RippleColor), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
                                 <Path.Data>
                                     <EllipseGeometry x:Name="rippleEllipse" Center="{Binding (helper:MouseHelper.LastDownPosition), ElementName=templateRoot, TargetNullValue={StaticResource zero}}" RadiusY="{Binding RadiusX, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
                                 </Path.Data>
                             </Path>
                             <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                         </Grid>
                     </Border>
                     <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                             <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{Binding (local:ButtonRipple.BackgroundMouseOver), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
                         </Trigger>
                     </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                 </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
     </Style>
 </Window.Resources>
```

В копии видно что у любого Binding который содержал Path в исходном стиле. Path был удалён.
Подскажите как сделать чтобы при копии шаблона Path не удалялся